# Summarize Within Returns with zero values

Tags: arcgis-pro, summarizing

I am trying to summarize the areas of tree canopies (almost 2.3 million records) within each each city (Multipart). The tools runs without error, however the columns of interest are empty.

How can this fixed?

Cities CRS:

[image]

Tree Canopies CRS:

[image]

Tool:

[image]

Current output:

[image]

Comment: Try projecting the tree data into the same coordinate system as the cities layer.

Comment: Aren't they the same though? I already tried reprojecting the `tree data` using the cities layer's WKID. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I second @Hornbydd's suggestion. While project-on-the fly is useful for display, it is problematic with data comparison operations. (Note: GCS NAD 1983 HARN != PCS NAD 1983 HARN StatePlane Florida....

Comment: @Vince, thank you, can you please explain it a bit further, as I am having trouble fully understanding your comment.

Comment: That state plane projection is based on the same datum as the geographic coordinate system, but they are not equivalent (they aren't even both projected)